# Order rows by how they appear in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables that I'm joining:

`featured_products`

```
item_id
999
234
700
```

`products`

```
item_id    price
234        10.00
700        15.50
999        5.30
```

I need to join both tables but keep the order in which they appear in the `featured_products` table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN featured_products f ON p.item_id = f.item_id
```

Expected results:

```
item_id    price
----------------
999        5.30
234        10.00
700        15.50
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not without an explicit/proper sequence.

Comment: No. You will need to add another column to the featured_products table to order it by.

Comment: So what determines the order of your values? From your post it's clear that there is some meaning to the order `999`, `234`, `700`, so what is that meaning? Why is `234` after `999` but before `700`?

Comment: As a side note as well, SQL Server 2008 ran completely out of support in 2019; it is *long* past time you completed your upgrade path by now. The version hasn't had any security updates in excess of 3 years, and there are (multiple) known security issues.

Comment: By definition a table is an unordered set. There is no such thing as "the order they appear in the table". But what I suspect is want to order the sequence the rows were inserted? An identity column would work well for that.

Comment: Do you have more columns in `featured_products` like insertion_date, row_id, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I get the comments.  If order is important, you must add an ORDER BY clause.  If there is no column that defines the order you want, it gets tedious.  An order by item_id or price would be easy, but you have something custom.  I don't understand the logic.

If you need to manually define the order, adding a column of values to define the order for use in a ORDER BY clause might be the way to go.

To force this order for just these 3 records, a case statement can be used.

```
ORDER BY CASE p.item_id WHEN 999 THEN 1 WHEN 234 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

If you want another order, you will have to do a little more work.  (We can help if you share the requirements.)

Any order you happen to see in results without an ORDER BY clause will likely be because an index used to provide the data was in that order.  If the query goes parallel, there might be segments of stuff in order, not all of it.